# QGIS Cloud Coordinate Display Issue

Tags: qgis-cloud

I'm using QGIS 2.18.3 with the cloud plugin. The map that I've published using the plugin doesn't seem to be retaining the coordinate display setting that I specify in Project-Project Properties-Coordinate Display. Could this be a problem with the plugin, or is there some other place I have to specify the setting to get it to display correctly in a published map?  Other project properties seem to publish just fine.

Comment: I've opened a ticket with QGIS Cloud support.  If I get resolution, I'll post it here in case anyone encounters a similar issue.

Comment: It appears that the QGIS Cloud Plugin does not currently look at QGIS project properties and pull the coordinate settings.  It seems to use the project projection and displays the units for that projection as a default.  If you want decimalized degrees, you need to make sure the CRS for the project is a projection that supports them.  However, since the plugin doesn't pull the coordinate display settings, it also doesn't pull the precision, and displays degrees as rounded whole numbers.  I'm still working with their support.

Comment: The issue is fixed in QGIS CLoud plugin revision 1.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've gotten about as far as I can with QGIS Cloud Support on this issue.  For now, the project CRS in QGIS needs to support the desired QGIS Cloud coordinate display units, and they can't fix the rounding issue with 'decimal' degrees until they've looked at it a bit more closely to come up with a solution.